# UITextView is not firing up inside a UICollectionViewCell

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitextview, uicollectionviewcell

I have a UITextView that's inside a view that belongs to a UICollectionViewCell. Unfortunately when I tap on the UITextView nothing happens. textViewDidBeginEditing is not called at all. All the delegates are setup properly such that the buttons in said view work just fine.

UITextView -> UIView -> UICollectionViewCell

However, when I call becomeFirstResponder to a cell's view's textview, it fires up the keyboard and works just fine. What might cause this problem? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is most likely because the `UITableViewCell` is receiving the touch input and not passing it to the `UITextView`. You can programmatically call the `UITextView` inside `didSelectItemAtIndexPath`.

Comment: Is there a way to get the tap's coordinates in didSelectItemAtIndexPath or should I implement a tap gesture on the collectionview instead?

Comment: @liquidpenguins You can easily get the coordinates of the tap gesture inside the CollectionView using `touchesBegan:withEvent` or adding a gesture recogniser inside the collection view.